# Sharepoint Online Search Center How to Add Custom Secondary Form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, enterprise-search

On Sharepoint Online, on the Search Center main page, my users require a secondary custom search form like this:

[image]

I added a Script Editor Web Part, entered a table, form and fields as shown above, but don't know how to specify the form action to call the same results page as the main Search Box, HTML code follows:

```
<form name='DocNumForm' action='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SEDASearch/Pages/results.aspx?k=' method='get' target='_blank'>
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'>
    <tr>
        <td><font size='-1'>Prefix:</font><br><input type='text' name='Prefix' size='5' maxlength='2' value=''></td>
        <td><font size='-1'>Series:</font><br><input type='text' name='Series' size='5' maxlength='3' value=''></td>
        <td><font size='-1'>Base:</font><br><input type='text' name='Base' size='5' maxlength='3' value=''></td>
        <td><font size='-1'>Suffix:</font><br><input type='text' name='Suffix' size='5' maxlength='2' value=''></td>
        <td><font size='-1'>Revision:</font><br><input type='text' name='Revision' size='5' maxlength='2' value=''></td>
        <td><font size='-1'>&nbsp;</font><br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

How do I do this? What should I use for the action value?

Comment: Are they all managed properties? (prefix, series, base, suffix, revision) or it's just one column?

Comment: Thx @YogaPanda, Yes, they are all managed properties...

Comment: Then it will be easy to use advanced search webpart, writing an answer and will post it later,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire search via javascript input:

```
function fireSearch() { 
    var link = "";
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(event) {     
        event.preventDefault();     
        var queryString = $('#input').val();     
        var location = "/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?&k=" + queryString; 
        link = location;    
        $('#input').attr("value", '');  
        window.location.href = link;    
        return;
    });
}

fireSearch();​
```

Reference from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943597/window-location-replace-is-not-working-in-my-sharepoint-site

If you want to do it with no code solution, you can use advanced search.
Open advanced search page, modify the webpart, export the webpart, edit your search page and upload it. Let me know if step-by-step screenshots will be helpful.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thx Again @YogaPanda. My users require a Search Center main page form addon like the one I have prototyped above, and object to using the Advanced Search page as you have shown...
Can you show me how I would implement this js function from the form tag in my HTML example? I'd be much obliged : )